# KSH - if/then/else vs. double amps (&&) and double pipes (||)

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I am wondering what are the best practices regarding if/then/else ; I tend to use the following form (because I find it easier to read)

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
#

[[ -f /path/to/target/file ]] && {
    echo "File exists"
} || {
    echo "No such file"
}
```

instead of this form

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
#

if [ -f /path/to/target/file ] ; then
    echo "File exists"
else
    echo "No such file"
fi
```

I also include a `true` statement just before `} || {` for complex block, to ensure that "else" part will not be executed.

What are your recommendations ?

Comment: Your first example is a fairly unusual style.  Can't say that I've ever seen anyone use that consistently. I can't think of anything to say to not use it, however.

Comment: Actually, I'm using it since years, and it seems that it is not confusing anybody.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with that style is that the two forms aren't equivalent.  When you use:

```
if command; then
    foo
else
    bar
fi
```

then either `foo` or `bar` will be called, never both.  When using both `&&` and `||`, both paths can be taken:

```
$ [[ -d / ]] && {
> echo "Path 1 taken"
> false
> } || {
> echo "Path 2 taken"
> }
Path 1 taken
Path 2 taken
$
```

When using the `if cmd; then foo; else bar; fi` form, the condition for `bar` being called is `cmd` returning false.  When using the `cmd && foo || bar` form, the condition for `bar` being called is `cmd && foo` returning false.

EDIT: I just noticed that in your question you acknowledge that you need to put `true` at the end of blocks to make your version work at all.  If you're willing to do that, I'm not aware of any other major issues - but I'd argue that a style that requires you to unconditionally add "true" as the last command in a block if there's any possibility that the previous command could fail just guarantees that you'll eventually forget it, and things will look like they're working correctly until they don't.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion if-then-else is easier to read for someone who writes in any other language.
But my recommendation would be to use the short notation (with && or ||) only for one-liners with only one of the `&&` and `||`.
Some code like

```
[[ -d mustExist ]] || errorFunction "Dir mustExist is missing"
[[ -f toBeSend ]] && sendFile toBeSend
if [[ -d sometimes ]]; then
   writeTrueBlock
else
   writeFalseBlock
fi
```

EDIT: New thought: It might be even better to write this like

```
test -d mustExist || errorFunction "Dir mustExist is missing"
test -f toBeSend && sendFile toBeSend
if [[ -d sometimes ]]; then
   writeTrueBlock
else
   writeFalseBlock
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

**Readability and Style**

I tend to use the `&&` and `||` operators quite a lot in my scripting.

I even use more than one in a single statement, but only in sections that check whether to *continue* in the current block.

*Example1:*

```
for word in $list; do
    condition1 $word || continue
    condition2 $word || continue

    : do stuff with $word
    : do more stuff with $word
done
```

*condition1* and *condition2* act as assertions.  We get the exceptions
*out of the way*, and continue with what this piece of code is 
supposed to do.

Using `if` ... `then` ... `fi` in this case would be a bit awkward.

Alternate notations:

*Example2:*

```
for word in $list; do
    if condition1 $word && condition2 $word; then
        : do stuff with $word
        : do more stuff with $word
    fi
done
```

In *example2* we have another level of indent, while nothing
extra is happening.

*Example3:*

```
for word in $list; do
    condition1 $word && condition2 $word || continue
    : do stuff with $word
    : do more stuff with $word
done
```

If the two conditions can be expressed simply, I sometimes combine
them like in Example3.

---

P.S: I originally added an Exercise for the shell programmer: *Only two out of three examples are fully equivalent.  Which is the odd one out?*
As it happens, the difference I thought there was, wasn't there.
I actually wrote a [`shpec`](http://github.com/rylnd/shpec) test:

```rb
describe "continue"
  it "discards last exit status"
    (for i in 1; do
     false || continue
     done
    )
    assert equal 0 $?
  end
end

shpec/continue_shpec.sh
continue
  discards last exit status
  1 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: In the first and third the *condition1* can depend in some degree upon the the return of the last *condition* series of tests, whereas the `if...fi` statement will return true even if the *condition && condition* test fails. Although, that doesn't work as written actually - you would need to invert `|| ! continue` in order for it to work because `continue` is a true - to pass a failure along if needed. This is because `if...fi` returns for its execution block - not its test block, but simple commands in *AND/OR* lists return for themselves.

Comment: @mikeserv I don't get what you're trying to say about `|| continue`. Important thing here is that `continue` will preserve the value of `$?` for when it might drop out of the loop. The `if` construct discards it.

Comment: No - `continue` returns true unless it cannot `continue`. So `|| continue` most of the time - returns true. `|| continue` just trues a failed test. You could pass it on to the next iteration like `|| ! continue` though if you haven't set your test to handle the last iteration's failure and `break` properly, then you might wind up negating a final failure. POSIXly you could use the special assignment quality of the special builtins `continue`, `break` et. al and do `|| ret=$? continue` which won't work in `bash` or `zsh` unless special env vars instruct them them to behave properly.

Comment: @mikeserv I stand corrected.  Will update the post.

Comment: ...well... there's nothing in the answer to indicate otherwise...?

Comment: Apologies. Updated now.

Comment: No - I meant... why update it? It didn't indicate before that `continue` wasn't true...  By the way, `continue` will fail if you tell it to `continue` *too much*. Like... `continue "$?"` when `$?` is greater than the number of containing loops. So `|| continue "$(($?+LOOP_COUNT))"` will *not* be true, but in that case, it doesn't `continue` either.